# JavaScript: Basic function to go back/forward

Tags: javascript, html, function

So, I made a JavaScript function which helps me to define several parts that are hidden at first but can be shown when clicking a link (I suck at explaining, sry... you'll see what I mean when having a look at the code snippet)

The idea that I had then was to make a function that would show the next 'page' (make the id 1 higher) and another function that would go one 'page' back (reduce the id by 1, so to speak).

Here's the JS and HTML code:

```js
function change_page (id) {
 var content_raw = document.getElementById(id);
 var content = content_raw.innerHTML;
 var display = document.getElementById('replace');
 display.innerHTML = content;
}

function page_back () {
 //function to go one page back
}

function page_forward () {
 //function to go one page forward
}
```

```html
<div id='replace'>
This is page 1 (shown by default)
</div>

<div style='display:none;'>
 <p id="1">This is page 1</p>
 <p id="2">This is page 2</p>
 <p id="3">This is page 3</p>
 <p id="4">This is page 4</p>
 <p id="5">This is page 5</p>
</div>

<p style="text-align:center; width:100%;">
 <a href="javascript:page_back()" style="float:left; margin-left:100px;">Back</a>
  <a href="javascript:change_page('1')">Page 1</a> |
  <a href="javascript:change_page('2')">Page 2</a> |
  <a href="javascript:change_page('3')">Page 3</a> |
  <a href="javascript:change_page('4')">Page 4</a> |
  <a href="javascript:change_page('5')">Page 5</a>
 <a href="javascript:page_forward()" style="float:right; margin-right:100px;">Forward</a>
</p>
```

I really hope that you guys can help me because although I can programm quite well in PHP, I hardly can with JS.

Comment: In the `change_page` function set forward `a`'s  some attribute  to `id`+1, and back `a`'s  attribute to `id`-1. The get the `a`'s attribute in `forward`, `back` functions. Or keep a global variable containing current page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a helper variable

```
var currentPage = 1;
```

Then, in the change_page function you would always update this value

```
function change_page (id) {
    currentPage = id;
    ...
```

And the page_back/page_forward would be calling change_page function with either increased or decreased value of currentPage. So page_back could look like this

```
function page_back() {
    change_page(currentPage - 1);
}
```

Lastly, you need to make sure that the page_back and page_forward will never result in trying to load a page below 1/above the actual number of pages. To secure that, in the change_page function, you could check whether id is not less than 1 and at the same time it is smaller than max number of pages. The check could look like

```
function change_page (id) {
    if (id < 1 || id > 5)
        return;

    currentPage = id;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a global variable to store the current page you're in.

```js
function change_page (id) {
_currentPage = id;
var content_raw = document.getElementById(_currentPage);
var content = content_raw.innerHTML;
var display = document.getElementById('replace');
display.innerHTML = content;
}

function page_back () {
change_page(_currentPage-1);
}

function page_forward () {
change_page(_currentPage+1);
}

// global variable
var _currentPage;
```

```html
<div id='replace'>
This is page 1 (shown by default)
</div>

<div style='display:none;'>
<p id="1">This is page 1</p>
<p id="2">This is page 2</p>
<p id="3">This is page 3</p>
<p id="4">This is page 4</p>
<p id="5">This is page 5</p>
</div>

<p style="text-align:center; width:100%;">
<a href="javascript:page_back()" style="float:left; margin-left:100px;">Back</a>
 <a href="javascript:change_page('1')">Page 1</a> |
 <a href="javascript:change_page('2')">Page 2</a> |
 <a href="javascript:change_page('3')">Page 3</a> |
 <a href="javascript:change_page('4')">Page 4</a> |
 <a href="javascript:change_page('5')">Page 5</a>
<a href="javascript:page_forward()" style="float:right; margin-right:100px;">Forward</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code**

**[Working JSFIDDLE Here](https://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/te0c87f1/)**

```js
var curPage = 0;
function change_page (id) {
 var content_raw = document.getElementById(id);
    curPage = parseInt(id);
 var content = content_raw.innerHTML;
 var display = document.getElementById('replace');
 display.innerHTML = content;
}

function page_back () {
 //function to go one page back
    if(curPage==1)
        return;
    var content_raw = document.getElementById(curPage-1);
    curPage = curPage-1;
 var content = content_raw.innerHTML;
 var display = document.getElementById('replace');
 display.innerHTML = content;
}

function page_forward () {
  if(curPage==5)
        return;
    var content_raw = document.getElementById(curPage+1);
    curPage = curPage+1;
 var content = content_raw.innerHTML;
 var display = document.getElementById('replace');
 display.innerHTML = content;
}
```

```html
<div id='replace'>
This is page 1 (shown by default)
</div>

<div style='display:none;'>
 <p id="1">This is pagse 1</p>
 <p id="2">This is paage 2</p>
 <p id="3">This is page 3</p>
 <p id="4">This is page 4</p>
 <p id="5">This is page 5</p>
</div>

<p style="text-align:center; width:100%;">
 <a href="javascript:page_back()" style="float:left; margin-left:100px;">Back</a>
  <a href="javascript:change_page('1')">Page 1</a> |
  <a href="javascript:change_page('2')">Page 2</a> |
  <a href="javascript:change_page('3')">Page 3</a> |
  <a href="javascript:change_page('4')">Page 4</a> |
  <a href="javascript:change_page('5')">Page 5</a>
 <a href="javascript:page_forward()" style="float:right; margin-right:100px;">Forward</a>
</p>
```

**[Working Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/te0c87f1/)**